# Semantic Mediawiki 1.8.0 does not show page properties in custom namespace

Tags: properties, configuration, namespaces, mediawiki, semantics

I'm running Semantic Mediawiki version 1.8 (in a version 1.20.2 Mediawiki). Extensions installed: Semantic Drilldown (1.2.5), Semantic Forms (2.5.1), Semantic Forms Input (0.7), Semantic Internal Objects (0.7.1).

My goal is generating a training overview in a custom namespace 'Training' by querying pages with category 'Training' (which are all in this namespace). However, the pages which are within the namespace don't show up as results, whereas pages with the same content but outside the namespace (i.e. without a namespace, in (Main)) do show up. Looking at the properties of both pages show that properties for the page in the Training-namespace are not applied.

The overview lives in the same namespace under `index.php?title=Training:Start` with the following query:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Training]]
|?day
}}
```

I have two pages in the Training category, one inside and one outside the namespace. Only the one outside the namespace is shown as a result to the query above. Content for both is the same:

```
[[Day::Weekday]]
[[Category:Training]]
```

When I open the 'Browse properties' on both pages I get the following: http://screencast.com/t/WMUxc0vK

Is it an SMW configuration setting? I tried  several options from http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Configuration like:

- $wgNamespacesToBeSearchedDefault
- $smwgNamespaceIndex
- $smwgNamespacesWithSemanticLinks
- $smwgQDefaultNamespaces

but none seem to work. Does anyone have a clue what could be the problem?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set

```
$smwgNamespacesWithSemanticLinks[NS_TRAINING] = true;
```

in the LocalSettings.php file for it to work.

Do not forget to do a data refresh afterwards [1] or even better use the SMW_refreshData.php script.

The fastest way to get help with Semantic MediaWiki is the SMW mailing list. [2]

Cheers

[1] https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Repairing_SMW%27s_data#Using_Special:SMWAdmin

[2] https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/semediawiki-user